# How to determine a const in some model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following model for 'delivery_types' table:

```
class DeliveryType < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I want to determine a special delivery type, for example, "DELIVERY_BY_TIME", and I want that this const returns DeliveryType.first (I'll put info about this type in my table later). Is it possible? How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: whats the purpose in saving an ActiveRecord object in a Ruby Constant ? instead you can `.first` on the `DeliveryType` itself

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, as this is no "real const". What you could do though, is creating a class method, called "by_time", which returns your "by_time" object. I would also not rely on the fact that this is your "first" object. Rather I would use a "find_or_create_by_name("BY_TIME"), which always makes sure you deliver the right object. Combined, something like

```
def self.by_time
  @@by_time||= find_or_create_by_name!(name: 'BY_TIME')
end
def by_time?
  self == DeliveryType.by_time
end
```

If you read "Rails anti-patterns", they discourage you from making separate classes for "status" fields. They recommend to just use a string for that in your parent object, with some validators that limit the list of values though...